# Creacion de figura en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Alguien sabe cómo se podría hacer la siguiente figura en flutter.
[image: Contenedor con bordes redondeados]

He estado investigando y no he encontrado mucho, se me ocurre moldear varios contenedores con la esquina redondeada, pero alguién conoce alguna otra manera o alguna forma adecuada de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer fácilmente con `CustomPainter` , aquí tienes un ejemplo que preparé:

```dart
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: ClipPath(
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: MyPainter(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    final side = 50.0;
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.grey[700];
    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    for (int i = 0; i < size.height / side; i++) {
      path.addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTWH(
              i * side, size.height - side * (i + 1), size.width, side),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(side / 4),
        ),
      );
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes cambiar el valor de `topLeft` según tus necesidades